# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.backend' has no attribute 'tf' in Custom Regularizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am making using a custom regularizer that I will use in the first hidden layer weights in my model

**Data**

```
XTrain,YTrain),(XTest,YTest)=mnist.load_data()
XTrain=XTrain.reshape(XTrain.shape[0],XTrain.shape[1]*XTrain.shape[2])
XTest=XTest.reshape(XTest.shape[0],XTest.shape[1]*XTest.shape[2])
YTrain=to_categorical(YTrain)
YTest=to_categorical(YTest)
```

**Custom Regularizer**

```
def layer1_reg(weight_matrix):
        return 0.01*K.sum(K.sqrt(K.tf.reduce_sum(K.square(weight_matrix), axis=1)))
```

**Model**

```
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(500,activation='relu',input_shape=(784,),kernel_regularizer=layer1_reg))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001))
model.fit(x=XTrain,y=YTrain,batch_size=32,epochs=10)
```

**Error Message**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-db27f84e12fe> in <module>()
     22 
     23 model=Sequential()
---> 24 model.add(Dense(500,activation='relu',input_shape=(784,),kernel_regularizer=layer1_reg))
     25 model.add(Dropout(0.1))
     26 model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))

5 frames
<ipython-input-124-dc68394d8544> in layer1_reg(weight_matrix)
      1 def layer1_reg( weight_matrix):
----> 2   return 0.01*K.sum(K.sqrt(K.tf.reduce_sum(K.square(weight_matrix), axis=1)))

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.backend' has no attribute 'tf'
```

How to fix this error in my latest tensorflow and keras version as some people have suggested to use the previous version of tensorflow, but I cannot do that based upon my newer tensorflow and keras requirements setup?

Comment: please share 'imports' part of your code

Comment: tf.reduce_sum instead of K.tf.reduce_sum ?

Answer (score 1):

In function:

```
def layer1_reg(weight_matrix,l1=0.01):
        return l1*K.sum(K.sqrt(K.tf.reduce_sum(K.square(weight_matrix), axis=1)))
```

I'm guessing K is

```
import keras.backened as K
```

K has not attribute tf(tensorflow)

you should rather use tf.reduce_sum() instead of K.tf.reduce_sum()
and most important try to use only one module tensorflow.keras or keras both are different